# Sitting for long periods of time hurts my lower back. What can I do?

Tags: work-environment, work-life-balance, ergonomics

I like my job as a programmer but I heard all about the permanent damage that sitting can cause on the lower back. Right now my lower back is annoying me and I cannot focus on my job­. Some days it is not too bad, but today sitting for *any* length of time is causing me discomfort.

How can I address this with changes to my workstation?

Comment: Try a standing-desk setup for at leas part of the day? And if you can get your company or your doctor to refer you to a physical therapist, they're the right expert to analyze what you're doing and how to correct it.

Comment: Yoga.  I fixed chronic back pain with Yoga.

Comment: If you touch a red-hot iron rod, it will hurt. What are your options, then? Don't touch the iron rod, right? You know that sitting for long period hurts your back, so what are your options? Don't sit for long periods, of course. Why would you look for any other options when the solution is so simple?

Comment: Take breaks every 45 mins and go for a walk

Comment: See http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/7260/how-do-you-remember-to-sit-up-straight/7271 and definitely watch the Esther Gokhale TED talk

Comment: What to do in general is out of scope.  However the simple change to ask how you can address this problem through changes to your workstation brings this back on topic.  If you have questions about how to address your issue to management that could also be a valid question one which should be asked seperatly.

Answer (score 6):

Standing desks are very nice. Especially if you can find one that has the option to lower into a regular seated desk. At my office I typically sit for the first 3 hours or so then use the remote on the desk to raise it to a standing desk and that gives my legs time to breathe and it gives my back a rest.

I understand that standing desks are not an option for everyone, so perhaps every hour just take a quick little walk around the office and *stretch*. You'd be amazed at how much of a difference stretching can make on your body.

Another small thing that makes a fairly large difference is getting some kind of footstool. While you're seated at your desk, usually your feet just hang straight down to the floor which, to me, eventually hurts my back. Get a stool that is maybe a foot tall and rest your feet on that sometimes. Alternate between the floor and the stool. It feels really nice on both your legs and your back.

And, of course, the cliche answers such as get plenty of sleep, exercise, etc will help you out in the long run as well.

Comment: Yep, walking around every hour is very recommended. If you're using Windows, I recommend [BreakTaker](http://www.techerator.com/breaktaker/), which will stay idle in your taskbar and notify you once every hour that you should get up and walk around. I use it daily for months now and it's really great in its simplicity :) .

Answer (score 4):

> I like my job as a programmer but I heard all about the permanent
>   damage that sitting can cause on the lower back.

It’s the most common “occupational hazard” a desk jockey can get. And the best solution is to simply not sit at a desk all day. How to deal with that depends on you and your workplace. Standing desks are an option. But for me, what I like to do is take walking breaks every few hours. Even if it is a simple walk around the block, that helps your body adjust. Also, avoid sitting at your desk for lunch. If you have a 1 hour lunch, then I would recommend you spend 20-30 minutes walking somewhere. And then eating lunch.

The key is to not be sedentary in your workday. Which is quite tough to deal with and balance, but is doable if you consciously force yourself to do so.

That said, you say this.

> Right now my lower back is annoying me and I cannot focus on my job­.
>   Some days it is not too bad, but today sitting for *any* length of
>   time is causing me discomfort.
>
> What are my options?

If you are feeling pain right now and don’t see it going away, consider this a health issue, talk to your supervisor and take the rest of the day off as a sick day. Even arrange for a doctor’s appointment to have them officially check you out.

Now some people will recommend yoga and elaborate exercise, but I would say that even basic exercise like walking—as I initially recommend—would help you.

But past that if you feel this is getting bad another thing to consider is discussing this with your supervisor or human resources department and see if they can arrange for flex time or even see if you can work from home.

As a tech/programmer myself I know one thing: I will have bursts of creativity followed by lulls. When I work from home, being able to lay down and even take a nap saves my back and overall health immensely.

Also, be open minded to potential dietary issues. Issues with digestion and lower back pain go hand in hand. At one gig I was eating without thinking and then immediately going back to work. I ended up being constipated and that put pressure on my lower back which would often result in me being out from work for 2 to 3 days as my body recovered.

Past any of that, you might also want to assess which way your career is tacking. Meaning in 10 to 20 years do you really want to be sitting in front of a keyboard and glowing screen all the time? Or do you see yourself being more of a supervisor or even an instructor. Having programming skills does not necessarily mean you need to be hunched over all day.

That last part might seem like “pie in the sky” but honestly, your health is your health and chronic health issues caused by sitting at a desk might make you want to think about your skills and roles in the world in a better perspective.

Personally, I’ve been doing this kind of stuff for 20+ and I have to say that I myself am moving more towards the supervisor and instructional aspect of this career skill I have. My days of all-nighters sitting at a desk and eating junk are pretty much over. I try to balance desk time with non-desk time as much as possible and it’s improved my health and helped my career satisfaction a lot more than even I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Constantly sitting for hours on end would contribute to lower back pain, and you should be taking a break every so often to stand up, stretch a bit, and even walking to the break room to get a drink.

You need to take a break from focusing on work every 45-60 minutes anyway.

The solution might not need something as expensive as a standing desk - simply rearranging your workspace to give you a better seated posture would go a long way to helping. Desk height, monitor height, and seat height and support all go someway towards affecting your seated posture. One major issue is that most office furniture (especially cheaper) is standardised around "average" stature - so it doesn't fit anyone perfectly.

We've had ergonomics people come in and measure up people and suggest monitor stands, better seat setup, and so on.

And then there's desktop yoga - stretches and exercises you can do while you sit and work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider getting a [kneeling chair](https://www.google.com/search?q=kniestoel) or a [sitting ball](https://www.google.com/search?q=zitbal). Here is my knee chair:

[image]

Sitting on such a chair prevents your lower back from slumping (the reason I developed my lower back pain in the first place). I can sit on this an entire work day, whereas sitting in an ordinary chair will leave me with pain at the end of the day.

The company name that keeps popping up when you search for these is [Varier](http://www.varierfurniture.com/en_nl/Movement-Chairs/Variable-balans-R/Variations-Variable-Balans/Variable_Balans_Black_STE999-Natural_Ash).

I have tried a sitting ball (a.k.a. ability ball, Swiss ball, yoga ball or exercise ball) occasionally (one day at a time) and it works surprisingly well, but I have no personal experience using if for an extended period. When sitting on it you keep making small movements, adjusting your balance, posture, feet, which seems to be working. You will also have to straighten your back to keep your balance, slumping is impossible.

Note: [some people disagree](http://www.builtlean.com/2013/09/24/sitting-exercise-ball/) about using sitting balls.

*Ask around for friends/colleagues using one of these solution and lend their chairs when they are on holdiday.*

Answer (score 0):

Like you I have a weak lower-back, for me the key is exercise.

I train during lunch hours 3-5 times a week and I can manage sitting without too much discomfort thanks to that. You can do it outside work hours if your work is not cool with it.

It has happened to me that I've not been able to work out for a week and by that time my back was killing me.

Whether you're able to add exercise to your routine or not you need to consider the following as-well:

- I assume you have a standard work station with a standard office chair. Getting proper training in adjusting the chair to your body is crucial since everyone needs a unique setting in order for it to be as comfortable as it can be for you.
- If you're using a pillow for your chair or a stool of some sort for your feet to rest on then it means that your chair is not adjusted for you correctly (you shouldn't need it), as pointed out. Similar, if you need a silicon mouse-pad then the difference between the height of your chair and your table is not correct, you should be able to use a silicon-less mouse pad.
- Desks that allow you to stand are great, if you don't have one you should check if you can have one. Being able to stand up every now and then can do wonders on your back.
- The height and distance of your computer screen is [very important](http://pilates.about.com/od/faq/ss/How-To-Sit-At-Work_4.htm).
- Watch your posture, if you're not sitting with a straight back then you can almost guarantee some pain building up.

Exercise (in my case mainly running, but Bootcamp as-well) did it for me, but I find the other points very important as-well to maintain my lower-back happy.

I hope my answer helps you, I feel your pain.

**Edit**

This somewhat [duplicte](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6772/what-should-i-look-for-when-buying-a-desk-and-chair-for-computer-work/6773) most definitely will clear up some of the points I mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the other excellent answers given already, consider the quality of your desk chair - make sure you have an adjustable one that provides proper support. You may need to supplement the chair with a lower back cushion.

Definitely get up from your chair at regular intervals and walk and/or stretch.

Comment: Some factual information is here: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6772/what-should-i-look-for-when-buying-a-desk-and-chair-for-computer-work/6773